# Splitting of cone(f)

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

This is an exercise 1.5.10 in Weibel which I could't solve completely.
Let $C$ and $C'$ be split complexes with splitting maps s,s'. If $f: C \rightarrow C'$ is a morphism, show that $ \sigma(c,c') = (-s(c),s'(c')-s'fs(c))$ defines a splitting of cone$(f)$ if and only if the map $f_*;H_*(C) \rightarrow H_*(C')$ is zero.

We want to show $dsd=d.$

My solution so far calculates $ dsd(b,c)=(d_B(b) , -fsd_B + d_Cs'fsd_B - d_Cs'f(b) + d_C(c) )$.
I don't know how to get $:-fsd_B + d_Cs'fsd_B - d_Cs'f)(b)=-f(b)$ using  $f_*:H_*(C) \rightarrow H_*(C')$ is zero.

Answer (score 1):

An explicit calculation shows that
$$(dsd-d)(b,c) = (0,(1-ds')f(1-sd)b).$$
If this vanishes for every $b$, we have that $f_*[b]=[ds'fb-ds'fsdb+fsdb]=0$ for $db=0$, so indeed every closed element is mapped to an exact one.

In the other direction, if $f_*=0$, this meas that every element of the form $f(c)$ with $dc=0$ can be written as $f(c)=dt$ for some $t$. Since $f(1-sd)b$ is of this form, i.e. $d(1-sd)b=0$, we can write $f(1-sd)b=dt$ for some $t$ and we finally find
$$(1-ds')f(1-sd)b=(1-ds')dt=0.$$